# Python - Async callback/receiver for WebSocket

Tags: python, websocket, async-await, receiver

I am trying to implement WebSocket connection to a server (Python app <=> Django app)

Whole system runs in big Asyncio loop with many tasks. Code snippet is just very small testing part.

I am able to send any data to a server at any moment and many of them will be type request something and wait for response. But I would like to have some "always running" handler for all incoming messages. (When something in Django database will change I want to send changes to python app).

How can Include always running receiver/ or add callback to websocket? I am not able to find any solution for this.

My code snippet:

```
import asyncio, json, websockets, logging

class UpdateConnection:

    async def connect(self,botName):
        self.sock = await websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000/updates/bot/'+botName)
        
    async def send(self,data):
        try:
            await self.sock.send(json.dumps(data))
        except:
            logging.info("Websocket connection lost!")
            # Find a way how to reconenct... or make socket reconnect automatically

            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    async def DebugLoop(socketCon):
        await socketCon.connect("dev")
        print("Running..")
        while True:
            data = {"type": "debug"}
            await socketCon.send(data)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    uSocket = UpdateConnection()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(DebugLoop(uSocket))
    loop.run_forever()
```

My debug server after connection will start sending random messages to the client in random intervals and I would like to somehow handle them in async way.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needn't be that complicated. First of all, I suggest you use the context patterns offered by `websockets` module.

From the documentation:

> connect() can be used as an infinite asynchronous iterator to reconnect automatically on errors:
>
> ```py
> async for websocket in websockets.connect(...):
>     try:
>         ...
>     except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
>         continue
> ```

Additionally, you simply keep the connection alive by awaiting incoming messages:

```py
my_websocket = None

async for websocket in websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8000/updates/bot/' + botName):
    try:
        my_websocket = websocket
        async for message in websocket:
            pass # here you could also process incoming messages
    except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
        my_websocket = None
```

As you can see we have a nested loop here:

1. The outer loop constantly reconnects to the server
2. The inner loop processes one incoming message at a time

If you are connected, and no messages are coming in from the server, this will just sleep.

The other thing that happens here is that `my_websocket` is set to the active connection, and unset again when the connection is lost.
In other parts of your script you can use `my_websocket` to send data. Note that you will need to check if it is currently set wherever you use it:

```py
async def send(data):
    if my_websocket:
        await my_websocket.send(json.dumps(data))
```

This is just an illustration, you can also keep the `websocket` object as an object member, or pass it to another component through a setter function, etc.

Comment: Thank you :) this helped me to get it work as expected :)